# how can I solve keyerror when formatting string in pythong

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I just want the following outcome.
But I get `KeyError: '"msg_body"'`.

input:

```
text="text"
uid="uid"
input = '{"msg_body":{input_text}, "user_id":{input_uid}}'.format(input_text=text, input_uid=test)
```

wanted output:

```
'{"msg_body":"text", "user_id":"uid"}'
```

Single or double quotations must be exactly how it is above.
Thanks

Comment: Double the outermost braces

Comment: thanks and sorry for asking a duplicated question.